# нужно менять прозрачность объекта через слайдер

Tags: c#, unity3d

у меня этот скрипт должен менять прозрачность объекта, который изначально выключен, а когда я нажимаю на кнопку которая его включает, появляется его клон... но когда я включаю этот объект, прозрачность поменять не могу...  Ошибки в юнити нет, просто не меняется прозрачность...

```
    void Start()
{
    AsistantControllScript = FindObjectOfType<AsistantControll>();
    m_slider.onValueChanged.AddListener(ChangeAlphaOnValue);

    currentMat = currentGameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material;

}



void ChangeAlpha(Material mat, float alphaVal)
{
    Color oldColor = mat.color;
    Color newColor = new Color(oldColor.r, oldColor.g, oldColor.b, alphaVal);
    mat.SetColor("_Color", newColor);
 

}
void OnDestroy()
{
    m_slider.onValueChanged.RemoveListener(ChangeAlphaOnValue);
}

public void ChangeAlphaOnValue(float value)
{
    ChangeAlpha(currentMat, value);
}
```

Comment: Как-то вы странно вызываете ChangeAlpha(Material, float, Slider) - там три параметра, вы указываете 2.

Comment: типа так: ChangeAlpha(Material, float, Slider, alpha)? 

P.S.: я уже упоминал что когда я нажимаю кнопку которая отвечает за включение объекта, появляется его клон, при этом оригинал остается не активен, но если его сделать активным(просто в самом проекте, во время тестирования нажать на галочку в инспекторе) то его прозрачность менять с помощью этого скрипта можно, но прозрачность клона этого объекта менять нельзя...

Comment: P.S.: немного изменил скрипт...

Comment: Насколько я помню можно изменить альфа канал через material.color.alpha, но я не помню, есть ли у этого свойства сеттер. А так делаешь метод, который вызывается событием `OnValueChanged` у слайдера и настраиваешь сам слайдер по делениям там и все такое.

Comment: еще раз изменил скрипт, но проблема никуда не ушла - прозрачность оригинала менять можно прозрачность кклона нет

Comment: все, проблема решена! Спасибо всем кто старался помочь!:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что бы у обоих был один и тот-же материал, а не копии, то делается так:

```
[DisallowMultipleComponent]
[RequireComponent(typeof(Renderer))]

public class Foo : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField] private Slider _slider;
    private Renderer _renderer;

    private void Awake () {
        _renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
    }

    private void OnEnable () {
        if (_slider != null)
            _slider.onValueChanged.AddListener(SliderChange);
    }

    private void OnDisable () {
        if (_slider != null)
            _slider.onValueChanged.RemoveListener(SliderChange);
    }

    private void SliderChange (float value) {
        Color Color = _renderer.sharedMaterial.color;
        Color.a = value;
        _renderer.sharedMaterial.SetColor("_Color", Color);
    }
}
```

Comment: понял, спасибо Вам!